# How do I select a specific radio button in a group of radio buttons in typescript file?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I would like to select a specific radio button whenever something is selected from a dropdown on the page. How can I do so via the function in typescript that is called on the dropdown selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like HammerN'Songs propose, the angular way would be to bind the value to a property of the component. You can actually bind the property to both, radio and select, like this,

*radio-ng-model.example.ts*

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'radio-ng-model-example',
  templateUrl: 'radio-ng-model-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['radio-ng-model-example.css'],
})
export class RadioNgModelExample {
  favoriteSeason: string;
  seasons: string[] = ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn'];

  selectionChange(event) {
    console.log(event.value);
  }
}
```

*radio-ng-model-example.html*

```
<h2>Using a Radio</h2>
<label id="example-radio-group-label">Pick your favorite season</label>
<mat-radio-group
  aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label"
  class="example-radio-group"
  [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason">
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">
    {{season}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<div>Your favorite season is: {{favoriteSeason}}</div>

<h2>Using a Select</h2>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Pick your favorite season</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="favoriteSeason"
    (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">{{season}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I modified this example [Material Docs - Radio Example](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples), adding the select.

If you want to reset the radio, you just need to assign the bind property (to the radio) to the default value. In this case you will have to use two properties, something like this,

*radio-ng-model.example.ts*

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'radio-ng-model-example',
  templateUrl: 'radio-ng-model-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['radio-ng-model-example.css'],
})
export class RadioNgModelExample {
  selectSeason: string;
  radioSeason: string;
  seasons: string[] = ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn'];

  selectionChange(event) {
    this.radioSeason = this.seasons[0];
  }
}
```

*radio-ng-model-example.html*

```
h2>Using a Radio</h2>
<label id="example-radio-group-label">Pick your favorite season</label>
<mat-radio-group
  aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label"
  class="example-radio-group"
  [(ngModel)]="radioSeason">
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">
    {{season}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<div>Your favorite season is: {{favoriteSeason}}</div>

<h2>Using a Select</h2>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Pick your favorite season</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selectSeason"
    (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">{{season}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: So I just want to reset to the default radio button (i.e. the first one) ANY time someone selects something in the drop down. How do I use ng model to indicate I want the first button selected?

Answer (score 0):

How you do it will depend on how you have your radio buttons set up, but one way is to have your `mat-radio-group` track a variable via `[(ngModel)]`, which you can change in whatever function your dropdown calls.

See [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t1ruse?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-ng-model-example.html) for a simple example of how this sort of thing is supposed to be laid out.

As for dropdowns, you'll want to check out either `(change)` or `(ngModelChange)`, to do what the example button does with `(click)`.

Comment: @cabesuon Oops - It should be now.